# resive max 2 result of value in column MyType

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

In my tables I've same date with different type (MyType). I wants to revive max. 2 result of each different MyType  when Created (date) > 2017-04-10.

My Date:

```
ID MyType Created
1  A      2017-04-09
2  C      2017-04-09
3  D      2017-04-09
4  A      2017-04-12
5  A      2017-07-09
6  A      2017-11-08
7  C      2017-05-09
8  C      2017-09-12
9  C      2017-10-01
10 B      2017-04-09
11 D      2017-05-17
```

expected result:

```
ID MyType Created
4  A      2017-04-12
5  A      2017-07-09
7  C      2017-05-09
8  C      2017-09-12
11 D      2017-05-17
```

How to receive max 2 result of each MyType's column?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I don't think you can easily do this without session variables.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen FWIW, I think you can ;-) - although it won't scale so well.

Comment: See the tag I added.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  ID, 
    MyType, 
    CreatedDate
FROM
       ( Select ID, 
                MyType, 
                CreatedDate, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID Order by CreatedDate desc) [RN]
         From YourTable) A
WHERE 
    A.RN IN (1,2)
ORDER BY
    CreatedDate
```

Comment: This would be a great answer... if the OP wasn't using mysql

Comment: @Strawberry I connect by PHP (doctrine2) to database to receive date